# Vue3 Firebase Chrome Images not Loading

Tags: image, vue.js, google-chrome, vps

In my Vue3 project i am trying to use profile pictures for my users.
All of the profile pictures are saved in a public folder on my virtual private server as svgs.
Side info: The domain in my link does not have an SSL certificate

In Vue i just reference the path to the folder on my server and it all works just fine.
Using `npm run dev`, Safari and Chrome load all of the images as expected.

But as soon as i deploy hosting to Firebase, Chrome does not load the images anymore. Safari continues to work as expected.

It throws the error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I can not seem to find anything about this on the internet.
So why does Chrome not load the images correctly?

Comment: Try doing hard refresh(`Ctrl + Shift + R` or `Command + Shift + R`). Or right clicking on refresh button when dev tools are open and clicking `Empty Cache & Hard Reload` option.

Comment: Did not work for me sadly. When trying other devices that use Chrome, all fail to load the images